# Iterative grow a shuffled list in python

Tags: python, list, random

I am trying to iteratively shuffle a list of 4 elements, then append the shuffled list to a growing list. The result will be a list that is some multiple of 4 elements long, with every four elements being some combination of my original list.

My code is

```
import random
list1 = ['X','Y','Z','Q']
list2 = []
for drop in range(0,72/4):
     random.shuffle(list1)
     list2.append(list1)
```

The problem that I seem to have is that list2 will be the same shuffled version of list1 over and over.

Example list2: ['Q','X',Z','Y','Q','X',Z','Y','Q','X',Z','Y',...]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you wanted to write

```
list2.extend(list1)
```

Otherwise, you would add the **same** instance of the object list1 to list2 over and over again.

Comment: Is there a reason why list2.append(list1) adds the same instance over and over? My logic was that during each loop, list1 would get rearranged.

Comment: First, note that with `list2.append(list1)` you do not add the elements of list1 to list2. You add the list1 itself to list2 (['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'Q' ] vs. [['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'Q']]). Since no copy of list1 is being made, `random.shuffle(list1)` changes all the occurrences of list1 in list2.

Answer (score 2):

When you append a list to another list, you're not making a copy of that list - you're appending another reference to the original list. All of your attempts to append are really references to the same object, and a modification to one is a modification to all.

Here's a demonstration of this surprising result.

```
>>> list1 = ['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'Q']
>>> list2 = []
>>> list2.append(list1)
>>> list2.append(list1)
>>> list2
[['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'Q'], ['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'Q']]
>>> list2[0][0] = 'A'
>>> list2
[['A', 'Y', 'Z', 'Q'], ['A', 'Y', 'Z', 'Q']]
>>> list1[0] = 'B'
>>> list2
[['B', 'Y', 'Z', 'Q'], ['B', 'Y', 'Z', 'Q']]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you shuffle list1 in place, you shuffle all instances of list1. As you appending list1 to list2, you are just shuffling the same list over and over again.

Try using [deepcopy](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html)

```
import random, copy
list1 = [1,2,3,4]
list2 = []
for i in xrange(10):
    random.shuffle(list1)
    list2.append(copy.deepcopy(list1))
```

Comment: Maybe `copy.deepcopy()` is a bit too much here.  A simple `list1[:]` would do the trick.